# yii login error at amazon ec2 servers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii, authentication, amazon-ec2

i had a perfectly working login system in my localhost based on yii framework.

but once i uploaded the files to my amazon servers it gives an error saying

> Application runtime path "/var/www/html/dashboard/yii-Framework/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.
>
> /var/www/html/dashboard/yii-Framework/Yii/base/CApplication.php(289)

```
286     public function setRuntimePath($path)
287     {
288         if(($runtimePath=realpath($path))===false || !is_dir($runtimePath) || !is_writable($runtimePath))
289             throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Application runtime path "{path}" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.',
290                 array('{path}'=>$path)));
291         $this->_runtimePath=$runtimePath;
292     }
293 
294     /**
```

Comment: permissions problem, make sure you have set the chown and chmod of the files that require it.

Comment: you never said if it worked, let me know i am still watching this question.

Comment: sorry mate.. it dint worked, i changed the permission, it is a server problem

Answer (score 0):

give access to the server for writing the directory. use this command

```
    chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/protected/runtime
```

The application will then same error for assets. use the same command but replace "runtime" with "assets"

Answer (score 0):

I found that the runtime folder needs to be *owned* by the web server process.

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/protected/runtime
```

I'm not sure if this is something else wrong with my system or a yii thing.